# how does this async/await work when it's not being called in async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have a promise stored in a `const`

```
const goToWork = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('Go to Work'));
});
```

since calling `goToWork()` would error `expression is not callable`

I tried storing running it in an `async` function:

```
async function callPromise() {
  return await goToWork;
}
```

now awaiting `callPromise` as such `await callPromise()` returns `pending<Promise>` which tempted me to store it in another `async` function as such:

```
async function executePromise() {
  console.log(await callPromise());
}
```

and then ran it `executePromise()`
`// output: Go To Work`

my question is how come executePromise() didn't complain of not running in an `async` function ? how come it did not need to be "awaited"

Comment: something is driving that to resolve

Comment: `my question is how come executePromise() didn't complain of not running in an async function ?` Why would it complain? There is nothing preventing you from running an async function from a non-async function. `how come it did not need to be "awaited"` Again, there is nothing that forces you to await a async function.

Comment: `return await goToWork;` is almost certainly useless. It’s the same as `return goToWork;`, but then the entire `async function callPromise` can be removed. Promises are not functions; you don’t “call” a Promise. A Promise is already in the process of execution. If you want to call a function that initiates a Promise later, you would simply return a new Promise from a function, e.g. `const goToWork = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { setTimeout(() => resolve("Go to Work")); });`.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried storing running it in an async function:

There really is no point at all this this function:

```
async function callPromise() {
  return await goToWork;
}
```

It absolutely the same as:

```
function callPromise() {
  return goToWork;
}
```

which is a pointless function that doesn't do anything useful.  So, since you're making a function with no practical use, there must be some basic misunderstanding of async/await.

To start with, **all `async` function return a promise - always**.  So, `return await fn()` is not useful.  You may as well just do `return fn()`.  Both return a promise with the same state.

> now awaiting callPromise as such await callPromise() returns pending which tempted me to store it in another async function as such:

Yes, as I said above.  **All `async` functions return a promise**.

> and then ran it executePromise() // output: Go To Work

There should be no surprise here.

```
console.log(await callPromise());
```

This will output the result of `await callPromise()` which (if it doesn't reject) will output the resolved value of the promise that `callPromise()` returns.

> my question is how come executePromise() didn't complain of not running in an async function ? how come it did not need to be "awaited"

Here's your `executePromise` function:

```
async function executePromise() {
  console.log(await callPromise());
}
```

There's no problem with this function because the `await` is inside an `async` function.  That follows the `async/await` rules.

When you call it like this:

```
executePromise()
```

That just runs the function and because that function is an `async` function, it will always return a promise.  There is no rule that calling an `async` function requires using `await` on it or must be called from within another `async` function.

You can call it like this:

```
executePromise().then(...).catch(...)
```

Or, you can put it in a `async` function:

```
async someFunction() {
    try {
        await executePromise();
    } catch(e) {
        // got error
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Or, you can just call it without regard for the returned promise:

```
executePromise();
```

Calling it naked like this last one is not paying any attention to whether the returned promise resolves or rejects and is not paying any attention to any resolved value.  But, it's legal to do this.  It possibly sets you up for an unresolved rejection because there's no reject handler, but if you know that promise will never reject and you don't care when it resolves or what the resolved value is, then this is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how come executePromise() didn't complain of not running in an async function?

But it did run in an `async` function: `async function executePromise()`.

Keep in mind that `await` is syntactic sugar (more or less, see comments), and you can always turn it back into `Promise.then()`, where this:

```
const x = await Promise.resolve('foo')
console.log(x)
```

behaves similar to

```
Promise.resolve('foo').then(x => console.log(x))
```

This makes it easy to understand what is going on:

```
async function callPromise() {
  return await goToWork;
}
```

is similar to

```
async function callPromise() {
  return goToWork.then(x => x);
}
```

And

```
console.log(await callPromise());
```

can be thought of as

```
goToWork.then(x => x).then(x => console.log(x))
```

None of that needs to be awaited, but you can use `await` to make it more readable.

Comment: I have to disagree that it is syntactic sugar; the call stacks and related behavior are very different. Async/await also allows the JS engine to make some scope-related perf improvements (not yet implemented in V8, but planned to be; I don't know about other engines). See [Why Async/Await Is More Than Just Syntactic Sugar - Zhengao.io](https://www.zhenghao.io/posts/await-vs-promise) for more details and links.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Very interesting, thank you for the input! I dampened the claim in my answer, the point I wanted to make was that it can help to understand `await` when thinking of what a `.then()` would look like, not make statements about the difference on engine level, so I should not phrase it that way. The article is interesting, particularly the part about better stack traces is a very good point.